# Which version of GeckoDriver should I use with Firefox 32-bit on a Windows 10 64-bit system?

Tags: java, firefox, selenium-webdriver, selenium-firefoxdriver, geckodriver

Our client requires us to have the most recent version of Firefox for testing their site, so we're upgrading from `Firefox 44` and `Selenium 2.53.0` (for Java) to `Firefox 51.0.1` and `Selenium 3.0.1`. We're attempting to use the latest `GeckoDriver` version (`0.13.0` as I write this) to support the latest Firefox version, but I'm struggling to get it to run.

For our `Windows 10 64-bit` machines with `Firefox 32-bit`, should we install the 32-bit or 64-bit `GeckoDriver`?

Comment: I ended up having other errors; namely, the framework we use atop Selenium needed an update to the same Selenium version as our test project. Thanks for the help though =)

Answer (score 0):

I'm running Firefox 51.0.1 (32 bit) on Windows 10 and geckodriver 0.13 with Selenium 3.0.1. Both the 32 bit and 64 bit versions of geckodriver work fine for me.

Answer (score 0):

My selenium script is working with geckodriver-v0.13.0-win64 in firefox 51.0(32-bit). Can you please check JDK version ? I should be 1.8.0 or grater. I am using jdk1.8.0_101 and jre1.8.0_101. Please share console error

Answer (score 0):

You can use [webdrivermanager](https://github.com/bonigarcia/webdrivermanager/) to automate the download of the latest version of *geckodriver* for your platform.

Comment: I'm not interested in the latest version; I've already covered that

Comment: This library also allows you to manage old versions of geckodriver.